# Factorization of the Fokker-Planck semigroup

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

I have posted this question on stackexchange over four month ago, but didn't get an answer: "In the classical theory of Markov processes, the Fokker-Planck semigroup $\{T_t:t\ge 0\}$ can be factored as $T_t=N\circ U_t \circ j$, $t\ge 0$, where $j$ is an embedding, $U_t$ is a group of automorphisms, and $N$ is a conditional expectation." This is a direct quote from the book "Dilation of Irreversible Evolutions in Algebraic Quantum Theory" by D.E. Evans and J.T. Lewis. Could anyone please provide me with a concrete reference where I can find the proof of the statement above?

Thanks!